# MongoDB: query nested arrays with pagination

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Lets say I have a collection of the following documents:

```
{
  _id,
  profile: {...},
  arrayProp1: [....],
  arrayProp2: [....],
  arrayProp3: [....],
  ...
}
```

Number of objects in arrayPropX arrays may be become big, at least thousands. So I need to use pagination and the question is what is the best way to do this?

For example how to return:

1. Total number of elements in arrayProp1 for specified _id
2. X elements from position Y in arrayProp1 for specified _id
   ?

Same as above but with filter on some field on arrayProp1 elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two operators: [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) and [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { _id: queryId }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            size: { $size: "$arrayProp1" } 
        }
    }
])

db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { _id: queryId }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            sliced: { $slice: ["$arrayProp1", Yposition, Xelements] } 
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine, but what if I need to sort array before slice? Looks like it is not possible without $unwind first?

Comment: @ДмитрийАлферьев that is correct, you have to `$unwind` - sorting inner array is one of the features I would like to have in MongoDB